# Does the law of large numbers pin down the distribution of an infinite sample?

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Imagine you draw (independently) an infinite amount of draws from a random variable with infinite support, and the strong law of large numbers applies. We know the average for sure will be equal to the mean. Can we further say that, since the size of the sample is infinity, the distribution of the draws will be exactly the distribution of the random variable?

Comment: Well, you have different versions of the LLN just gives you convergence in probability. The strong version just gives you a,s (almost surely), but I don't see anything about the distribution of the draws.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions a version called borel's law, stating that if you repeat the draw a large number of times, the number of times an event occurs converges to the probability of the event. I wonder if from there one can state that the distribution of infinite draws will be the distribution of the random variable. It seems I am taking too limits at the same time and don't know how to make the statement rigorous.

Comment: I think the answer is YES. Let $P$ be the probability of finding $x$ in some interval ($x1, x2$). If you simulate this by sampling $N$ times, with $N$ increasingly large, then the number of hits in the interval ($x1, x2$) should indeed converge to the value $P*N$, in the sense that the relative error goes to zero. Since the interval is arbitrary, the result can presumably be generalized to the entire probability distribution.

Comment: Here is what is making me nervous. It seems to me that for that argument to go through, the cardinality of the sample needs to be $aleph_2$.    Believe it or not, the structure of the economic problem I am trying to solve restrict the sample to be of cardinality $aleph_1$.   Would it be correct to say that the statement doesn't hold under that conditions?

Comment: In standard notation, the infinity in $ n \rightarrow \infty$ refers to countable infinity, i.e. to $\aleph_1$. But wouldn't you then have to do the same infinite number of trials for _every_ event in your sample space to apply Borel's in order to get the full distribution ( or at least do it for every possible outcome)? I think otherwise  the result you refer to deals with individual events , not the full distribution.

Comment: The answer is obviously yes and, since every sensible definition of the limiting frequencies of a sample involves a countable sample, considerations of alephs are quite offtopic here. To prove the result, indeed the SLLN suffices (see @M.Wind's comment, replacing the cautionary "should" and "presumably" by affirmatives). For a quantification of the size of the sample needed for a given threshold of the error, look for "Glivenko-Cantelli".

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Did  -- Thank you. The reason that I formulated by comment cautiously, is that there might be examples of degenerate probability distributions that are difficult to emulate by means of sampling. For example a distribution that goes as $sin^2(1/x)$ in some interval around $x = 0$.

Comment: @M.Wind Nothing wrong with being cautious, if you ask me... :-) I mainly wanted to stress that you had already explained the content of my comment.